# How to handle multiple rows from SQL select query in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a simple C# windows form in which I have 6 text-boxes. Now I have a SQL query which returns 3 rows (it will always return 3 rows - query gets data from junction table and another table) and each row has 2 columns (Name and Email). What I want to do is populate these 6 text-boxes with the result from sql query like `Name 1` & `Email 1` should get the value of `row 1`, `Name 2` & `Email 2` should get the value of `row 2` etc etc.

I have searched here and there but I haven't been able to find a solution so please help me out. I know I need to apply some loop here but I am not able to find the logic here.

**Images for reference :**

SQL Query Result :

[image]

C# Win Form :

[image]

Code (which is obviously not the way to do it) :

```
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;
        SqlConnection con = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        String Name;
        String Email;
        string ConnectionString = "// my connection string...";
        con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        string CommandText = "//sql query goes here";
         cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText);
         cmd.Connection = con;
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(rdr.Read())
          {
                  Name = rdr["Name"].ToString(); 
                 Email = rdr["Email"].ToString();
          }

        con.Close();
```

Comment: You should really be using a repeater control for list like data.

Comment: Please show us your code on how you retrieve the data

Comment: if its only 3 sets, you can just as well hard code the control names.  Abstraction (I.E., a control loop) isn't really buying you much yet.

Comment: @Aron Isn't repeater control in asp only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two arrays of your textboxes

```
 TextBox[] names = new TextBox[] {txtName1, txtName2, txtName3};     
 TextBox[] mails = new TextBox[] {txtMail1, txtMail2, txtMail3};
```

Now after retrieving the reader for your table

```
int idx = 0;
while(reader.Read() && idx < names.Length)
{
    names[idx].Text = reader.GetString(0);
    mails[idx].Text = reader.GetString(1);
    idx++;
}
```

Of course this solution is strictly limited by your statement: *it will always return 3 rows*

Comment: Thank you Sir, you have just solved my problem. I can't believe I didn't think of arrays - how stupid of me....

Comment: what if I wanted to do same in `DataGridView`? I have added three columns in `DataGridView` and want to display Name1, Name2 and Name3.

Comment: Bind the DataGridView to a DataTable. It is a lot easier

Answer (score 1):

You may put result of query into DataTable. And later you can set textboxes to show data on each row of DataTable.